# How do I have two _Layout files in the same project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my View folder I have an _ViewStart.cshtml file where I have a default layout

```
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

In my shared folder I have 2 files _Layout.cshtml and _LayoutLogin.cshtml. On my login view I want to use _LayoutLogin file, so I have done this in the view :

```
@{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutLogin.cshtml";
}

<h2>Login</h2>
```

But it stil use the _Layout file. How do I use another layout file, I have search on the internet for souloutions but nothing is working at all.

Hope someone could help me, I am going crazy!!

Comment: Did you try to rename the _Layout.cshtml to something else? It is possible that it is a default name and every view inherit it if it exists.

Comment: That's all you need to do. If it's still loading the default layout, then you're not actually loading the view you think you are.

Comment: I have exactly the same, and it's working fine. Did you try to clean/rebuild solution? just in case...

Comment: I have try to rename the _Layout file, and I got an error that it could not find the layout. So the project is using the _Layout file

Comment: Mario Garcia : I have tried that and stille not working

Answer (score 0):

When you call the view from the controller you can specify a layout.

```
return View("Index", "_LayoutLogin", viewModel);
```

Comment: I have done this :  //
        // GET: /Account/Login
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View("Login", "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutLogin.cshtml");
        } and it still not work

Comment: Not getting any error, it is just use the default layout

Comment: Are you sure your layouts are different? What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: Yes they are different. Mvc 5

Comment: Very odd. Try creating a brand new MVC project and use the method above to verify it is just your project that it isn't working in.

Comment: I Will try that tomorrow

Comment: You likely have some conflicting code that is forcing your layout back to the default file. Check for any assignments of your layout (Find in Visual Studio for the whole project).

Comment: I found the error. I have a conflicting code thank you for the help :-)